# Haskell are partially applied functions faster?

Tags: performance, haskell

I was messing around with Haskell, and wondered if there were any differences in performances between these two functions:

```
count :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> Int
count xs e = foldr countCheck 0 xs
    where countCheck x
            | x == e = (1+)
            | otherwise = (0+)

count' :: (Eq a) => [a] -> a -> Int
count' xs e = foldr countCheck 0 xs
    where countCheck x acc
            | x == e = acc + 1
            | otherwise = acc
```

I tried the following code as a benchmark: `main = print (count [1..10000] 1)`, which resulted in the first (using partially applied `+`) function being slightly faster on average.

I mainly wondered because, to me, `count` is way more confusing to read than `count'`. Other than being "clever", I figured that another tradeoff must be that it's faster. So does using partially applied functions make code run faster? If so, why?

Comment: Could you outline your measurement methodology in more detail? I do not observe any difference (benchmarking ``whnf (count [1..1000000]) 1`` with Criterion, compiled with ``-O2``). Do your results change if you replace ``(0+)`` with ``id``?

Comment: @Bogdan I'm on an (unfamiliar) windows machine, so I don't really have access to great benchmarking tools. I used powershell's `Measure-Command`, compiled without optimizations. It only a reported a minor (but consistent) difference of about 100 milliseconds each run.

Comment: "compiled without optimizations" — maybe that's the key here? Have you tried the ``id`` thing? Also, [Criterion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/criterion) is a Haskell package, so if you have access to cabal, you may use it to measure the execution time more accurately.

Comment: I just bench marked these and got no difference. Well .0001 difference in favour of count'

Comment: I believe this known as (or at least very close to) "[pointfree style](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Points-free_style)."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well I took a look at the core from the following programs

```
main = print (count [1..100000] 1)
```

and

```
main = print (count'  [1..100000] 1)
```

Compiling these and prettying up the resulting core gives almost identical files, I've removed the not interesting bits about `[1..10000]` and `print` since they're identical.

count:

```
main_e = __integer 1
main7 = \ x -> x
main6 =
  \ a -> case a of _ { I# b -> I# (+# 1 b) }
main5 =
  \ x ->
    case eqInteger x main_e of _ {
      False -> main7;
      True -> main6
    }
```

count':

```
main_e = __integer 1
main5 =
  \ x acc ->
    case eqInteger x main_e of _ {
      False -> acc;
      True -> case acc of _ { I# x1 -> I# (+# x1 1) }
    }
```

So it actually generates almost identical core, with `count` generating slightly more complicated core. However inlining `main6` and `main7` and lifting the lambda abstraction into one gives completely identical core.

Since GHC can perform all the optimizations I'd be very surprised at any difference between the code's performance. And even more surprised if it was in favour of `count`.

The whole zen of Haskell is to just write clean programs and let the compiler deal with making it faster. If the non-`foldr` version is clearer, write that. But after reading `fold`s for a few years the `foldr` version looks clearer so I'd write that. The cool part though, it doesn't matter which you use since they both are compiled to the same code.

Comment: Did you compile with or without optimizations? I've started practising reading core and it feels like GHC often inlines very aggressively – I'm surprised `main6` and `main7` weren't inlined in this instance! Do you have any idea why it didn't do that?

Answer (score 1):

Using partially applied functions in programs compiled with sufficiently high level of optimization could hardly make them faster, only slower. Simply because in this case you provide the compiler with less information about your intents.

With the exception, if the partially applied function is given the name and `INLINE` pragma (in some special cases). This is a kind of hint for GHC.